# How to inspect chrome network activity in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to block URL css files from the google chrome network page in selenium python, I searched too much but I didn't find any way to block or edit anything in the network page.

I want to block CSS files before page load to save internet usage.